# A small size portable freeware to tell you the version of the USB port and USB devices

Tags: windows, gratis, portable, usb

I'm looking for a gratis tool displays all my USB ports and devices and if they are USB 2 or 3.

I want to be able to distribute the tool to end-users who don't know much about USB and the differences in the versions, they do know that "3 is better than 2".

The end-users have OS that are mainly Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8, so the more OSs are supported, the better.

The GUI should looks similar like the [Igorware 64-bits checker](http://www.igorware.com/64bit-checker) as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of Igorware 64-bit checker]

except that is shows USB 2 or USB 3 instead of 32 bit and 64 bits. So, it should be as simple and straight forward as possible.

It should display a list of USB 2 or USB 3 devices connected to the USB port under the report tab.

The Info tab should basically shows which USB port can support which USB version.

It would be also nice to have if it can inform end-user to plug their USB 3 device to a USB 3 port instead of a USB 2 port to take advantage of speed (assuming that the PC have the two version of USB port available.)

It can be one tool for each OS mention above (e.g. one for Win XP, one for Win Vista, one for Win 7 and the 4th one for Win 8) or a single tool for all OS mention above (e.g. One version for Win XP and Win Vista and Win 7 and Win 8).

Win XP refers to Microsoft Windows XP, while Win Vista refer to Microsoft Windows Vista. Same goes to Win 7 and Win8, which represent Microsoft Windows 7 and Microsoft Windows 8 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) would fit the bill here. It lists a wealth of information not least a column that shows the "USB Version". Mine shows v1.10 & v2.00 devices connected, I have no v3 kit. The blurb from the website read thus:

*USBDeview is a small utility that lists all USB devices that currently connected to your computer, as well as all USB devices that you previously used.*

*For each USB device, extended information is displayed: Device name/description, device type, serial number (for mass storage devices), the date/time that device was added, VendorID, ProductID, and more...*

*USBDeview also allows you to uninstall USB devices that you previously used, disconnect USB devices that are currently connected to your computer, as well as to disable and enable USB devices.*

*You can also use USBDeview on a remote computer, as long as you login to that computer with admin user.*

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to edit the answer. Currently the text is a copy from the website of that tool ([there is a relevant meta discussion on that topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/735/94)). Could you make it a personal recommendation that is tailored to the question? Please note that the OP has reworded his question and added details. I hope to see you around :)